# How can I reduce the response timeout in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, httpresponse

I have some http clients that sometimes take too long to complete the request and I want to cut them off after a specific length of time (say, 5 seconds).

I know that in web.config you can set the executionTimeout to be a value, but when I set it, the api doesn't seem to abide by it.

To test this, I'm creating a controller with `Thread.Sleep` set to a value greater than the value I'm setting in the web.config but the response is not being cut off.

Comment: ever managed to get this going?

Comment: Not like this. However I've had success using the Polly library. I'll add an answer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I've not managed to do this out of the box, I've had some success using [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly)

Answer (score 0):

You can set this value in web.config.  For example, to change the timeout for one specific page:

```
<location path="somefile.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime executionTimeout="180"/>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

The time is given in seconds.

Comment: According to MSDN documentation it only applies when the Debug is set to false.

Comment: Here is the link for MSDN documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Yup did that as well.

Answer (score -1):

Usually, the first and easiest thing to do is just change the configuration/system.web/sessionState@timeout value to something like “90”.  This should mean that you’d like your users’ sessions to be persisted until a 90 minute window of idle time has elapsed.

Change in web.config :

...
   
  ...

There’s a couple of issues that are tied together here:
The application pool’s worker process default idle timeout is also set to 20 minutes
The default mode of storing session state is in the IIS process

Application Pool Idle Timeout

The settings for the application pool can be found by clicking on Advanced Settings (IIS 7.5) on the application pool that the application is assigned to.
<--Image goes here -->

Ensure this value is set to the timeout of your session, at a minimum, to ensure that all sessions persist for the entire session timeout period.
The reason that these two values are dependent on one another is because the session information is actually stored within the worker process of the application pool. That is to say, if the worker process is shutdown or killed for any reason, the session information will be lost.

Session Storage Mode
There are the modes of storing the session information:

- InProc (or In Process) – Default – Stores session information within the IIS worker process
- StateServer – Stores session information in a separate process (the ASP.NET state service)
- SQLServer – Stores session information in a SQL database

The only mode that is vulnerable to losing session information on a worker process is when the state is stored in the worker process. Both StateServer and SQLServer modes are not affected by worker process resets. Likewise, StateServer and SQLServer modes are the only options when it is necessary to share session state across more than a single IIS server.

Comment: I'm looking for limiting the response timeout not session